# When passing a message from one activity to the next, that message always appears under anything else I write. How do I make it appear on top?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Temperature is the text that needs to be displayed at the bottom and activity_display_message is the 1337 that needs to be displayed at the top.

Comment: please show your background (java) code where you are trying to set the  temp value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

use two text view to show your value and "Temperature" text. you can use RelativeLayout to easily manage show temperature text at bottom.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_display_message"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tempValue"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Value"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Temperature"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:gravity="bottom|center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tempValue"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

and inside java write

```
TextView txtTempValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tempValue);
txtTempValue.setText(your_temp_value);
```

Comment: The value (temp value) will have to be next to the word(temperature), because I'm  also going to have to show weight, acceleration, speed, temperature, altitude, and pressure. But it works, thank you! I'll try to make it appear next to it.

Answer (score 2):

Add a `TextView` and use `textView.setText(your_string);` on it. I'm assuming you are trying to print the text on the `LinearLayout` currently.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"    
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.myapplication.DisplayMessageActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/activity_display_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/temperature"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Code,

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.activity_display_message);
textView.setText(your_string);
```

Comment: Thanks! What should I write in "your_string"? Sorry, total noob here.

Comment: Its the number that you want to display above "Temperate". "1337" as in the question.